# New Environment after Calling a Function inside another Function

Tags: python

I have this program:

```
a = 0
def f(c):
    a = c
    return a + g(a)
def g(b):
    return a + b
f(3)                     #returns 6
```

How does it return the value 6? So far I know how binding environments are created when the python interpreter evaluates a variable and a procedure. Also I know the details how a new environment is made when a simple function (in the sense it doesn't call a new function) is called. After the call g(a) inside f, is there a new environment created exclusive for g that is one level below the global environment, or one level below the environment of f?

Comment: `a` in `g()` is the global `a`. `a=c` only makes a local `a` for `f()` not for `g()`. It is called scoping and considering it an environment may be the cause of your conceptual misunderstanding.

Comment: Actually, I mean it, so that I can test what value g will capture

Comment: It's from MIT pdf notes, it is actually stated that environments are made when python evaluates function calls.

Comment: I can give you the links to pdf if you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same as:

```
a = 0
def f(c):
    var = c
    return var + g(var)
def g(b):
    return a + b
f(3)
```

And the same as:

```
def f(c):
    var = c
    return var + g(var)
def g(b):
    return 0 + b
f(3)
```

And even more simplified:

```
def f(c):
    return c + g(c)
def g(b):
    return b
f(3)
```

When only reading the values of global variables, you can use them inside a function just fine. But if you try to assign to a global variable you need to use the `global` keyword, or otherwise you shadow the global with the local variable:

```
x= 123
def foo():
    x = 999   # shadows global x
    print(x)  # 999
print(x)      # 123


x = 123
def foo():
    global x
    x = 999   # changes global x
    print(x)  # 999
print(x)      # 999
```

Comment: So the environment of g is created one level below the global environment?

Comment: Like any function, `g` creates its own local scope "under" the scope where it was defined. Python is lexically scope, not dynamically scoped.

Comment: I don't know how MIT notes define them "procedure-call environment". Anyways, I think I should adapt the word "scope" from now on.

Comment: Scopes are static, created when a function is defined; environments are dynamic. created when function is called. When a function is called, a new environment is constructed for the duration of the call to map names to the variables in the appropriate scopes.

Comment: @chepner Are scopes the same with binding environments? It was explained in the lecture notes how binding environments are made when python evaluates variables and procedures. Also, am I correct terming "environment" the context where subsequent or let me say function exclusive variables are made after a certain function is called?

Comment: Think of the environment as the combination of all relevant scopes. When you call `g`, the environment consists of the local scope defined by `g`, the global scope (in which `g` was defined) and the built-in scope. Unless you define functions inside other functions, those are the only three scopes you'll be concerned with for any given environment.